# Spring - multiple command class with AbstractWizardFormController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can i have a AbstractWizardFormController controller with different command class for each page ?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a hack to me, but sure --the formBackingObject() method is called for each page, so you can override that method and add code to determine which command object to return (based on which page view is being requested).

On the other hand, that's going to add complications when you handle each pages submission -- will you have to figure out which type of object you're getting and cast?  I'd rethink -- maybe this isn't really a wizard-type situation and you should have separate controllers?  Or perhaps you should look at Web Flow?  My experience is that the Wizard controller is useful if you're using it as envisioned, but when you start trying to squeeze it into a scenario it's not meant for, it becomes more complicated than helpful.